# Find which (not yet installed) conda-forge package a file is in

Tags: conda, conda-forge

How do I find out which package a file, say "uchar.h", is in when the package is not currently installed?  On my Debian 11 system, I would Google search for
`debian package uchar.h`
Searching for
`conda-forge package uchar.h`
gives no useful result.

Comment: got the same problem and still confusing

Answer (score 0):

Use the `conda package -w <filename>` command.

Docs:  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/package.html